# Golang DNS without CGO on a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: go, docker, dns, kubernetes, cgo

I got a api written in Golang and deployed in a Kubernetes cluster.
Meaning it runs inside a docker container with the scratch image.
To compile to a light image like scratch/alpine I need to turn off cgo.
But the net package does not work well without cgo. I know there is an issue with the net package because itself uses cgo.

All the services I need to use for this app are on another Kubernetes namespace, so the only way go get to it is using DNS. I am in a corner here.

I build the binaries with something like this

```
GOOS='linux' CGO_ENABLED=0 GODEBUG=netdns=go+1 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags -s -o ./dist/prod/api ./src/backend/api.go
```

Which by itself does not resolve the issue, but as stated [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4714) by [Brad Fitzpatrick](https://github.com/bradfitz) from the go team, there is a hackaround it. Which I finally got it to work like

```
//Connect is a function that connects to MOngoDB
func Connect() (*mgo.Session, error) {
    var host string
    if os.Getenv("KUBERNETES") == "true" {
        cmd := exec.Command("ping", "-c", "1", viper.GetString("MONGO-HOST"))
        var out bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &out
        _ = cmd.Run()
        match := regexp.MustCompile(`\(([^\)]+)\)`).FindStringSubmatch(out.String())
        host = match[1]
    } else {
        host = viper.GetString("MONGO-HOST")
    }

    inf := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{host + ":" + viper.GetString("MONGO-PORT")},
        Timeout:  5 * time.Second,
        Database: "admin",
        Username: viper.GetString("MONGO-USER"),
        Password: viper.GetString("MONGO-PASS"),
    }
    return mgo.DialWithInfo(inf)
}
```

It just cuts the output of a ping command and use the resolved ip instead of the hostname to avoid the issue with dns. But it adds an extra complexity that my app should not be handling. How can I make better?

Comment: That Go issue isn't related, and was also fixed 2 years ago, so I'm not sure why you're dropping it in here. `GODEBUG=netdns` is a runtime option, not a compile time option, so it has no effect here. The net package works fine without cgo, what issues are you having without it? If you did need cgo for other operations, you use the `netgo` tag to build without the cgo resolver.

Comment: @JimB Only thing that I am sure is that net.LookupHost return empty for my service  hostname and returns actual ips for let's say google.com.

Comment: I need to disable cgo to cross compile from OS X to scratch/alpine. Ain't that right?

Comment: OK I think I see what's going on, you're conflating a bunch of details here. Yes, you need to disable cgo to cross compile (well, not strictly speaking, but creating a cross-compiling toolchain is not a simple task). If you want to use the host resolver, you need to link to be able to link to the host resolver, hence you need to build on Alpine or something using the same libc. Since you're using docker, you shouldn't need to cross compile at all; build the binary in a container matching the target.

Comment: Since the DNS appears to be broken in some way, you may also need to set `GODEBUG=netdns=cgo` in the final container to force the use of the host resolver.

Comment: So I would have two dockerfiles. One with golang:alpine that would compile and output a binarie. And then Add to the scratch image? Do you got any reference on that workflow? @JimB

Comment: No references handy, but that's the basic idea. I prefer to have the build container output the tarball for the docker build context directly to stdout for the next stage, but you could send only the binary to stdout and COPY it yourself, or even just put any build artifacts in a mounted volume. As for the DNS not resolving to what you expect, I would ask about that behavior in a more kubernetes specific forum, as the Go resolver seems to be working as intended.

Comment: @JimB It is a go 1.7 issue. They took off .local away from dns resolution on 1.7.  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16739 Seems like its fixed on 1.7.1

Comment: That makes sense. I was assuming you were on go1.7.1